# Syntax Error on Date type input

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple table

**EMPLOYEE**

```
ID: int
Name: nchar(20)
Birthday: date
```

And I create a simple procedure to add new record to `EMPLOYEE` table

**ADD_NEW_EMPLOYEE**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ADD_NEW_EMPLOYEE
    @id INT,
    @Name NCHAR(20),
    @Birthday DATE
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE 
    VALUES(@id, @Name, @Birthday)
END
```

When I execute the procedure (right-click -> `Execute Stored Procedure...`), I get an error

> Incorrect Syntax near '-'

on the value of date.

The code execution panel:

```
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[ADD_NEW_EMPLOYEE]
        @id = 3,
        @Name = N'James Bond',
        @Birthday = 1995-06-06
```

However, if I change the `@Birthday` type in `ADD_NEW_EMPLOYEE` to `nchar` type.
The value is encoded as `@Birthday = N'1995-06-06'` and the procedure executes normally. But doing so make the declaration in the procedure not corresponding with the value type in the table.

Can you show me the way to fix this ?

The version I use is Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Please note that I execute the procedure with SQL Server (right-click on the procedure and choose "Execute Stored Procedure"), a table to fill value show up and i just have to fill in the data for variables.

**#UPDATE:**

So in the table to input value, I have to input `'1995-06-06'` with single quotes instead of `1995-06-06` without the quotes.

What if another program like C# execute this procedure and the caller function forget to enclose the date in quotes? Is this a bug in SQL Server 2014? I feel like a joke.

Syntax error on execute:

[image: This will cause syntax error....]

This will work, but too clumsy... (notice the quotes ' ' surround the date value)

[image]

If you put a value to `nchar` variable, on execution, the value will automatically enclosed in the quotes `' '` . For the `date` type, the value goes straight to execute without proper quotes enclosing. And that causes the problem.

Comment: Try this @Birthday = '1995-06-06'

Comment: Pretty sure you need to use quotation marks around it as it's a string that's interpreted as date.

Comment: Please note that I execute the procedure with SQL Server (right-click on the procedure and choose "Execute Store Procedure"), a table to fill value show up and i just fill in the data for the variable.

Comment: Every language have some protocols and you will have to follow them in order to communicate. Isn't joke if i forget to put semicolon at the end of c# line and compiler would not allow me to compile the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing single qoutes Wrap date into single quotes `'1995-06-06'`

```
@Birthday = '1995-06-06'
```

Comment: Yeah, but SQL Server doesn't surround those in single quotes, just @Birthday = 1995-06-06 and throws the error. Is this a bug in SQL Server 2014 ?

Comment: @Flint Can't say about this since I am not aware of this issue but date should send as string value

Comment: So in the data input table, i have to write '1990-08-08' insteads of 1990-08-08

Comment: That would be so stupid and easy to get error if another program like Windows Form C# execute this query an forget to enclose the date in the single quotes. This is so clumsy.

Comment: @ThangLeQuoc SQL Server also doesn't display the quotes around text values, ie the `James` in your screenshot. Rule of thumb, only numerical values can be handled without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Missing the semicolon and single quotes  date into insert query and single quotes '1995-06-06'

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES(@id, @Name, @Birthday);

@Birthday = '1995-06-06'
```

Answer (score 0):

**@Birthday** is not a INT data type.

for datatype other than INT,we need use single single quotation mark ''

```
 @Birthday = '1995-06-06'
```

Comment: Yeah, I know. But the things is, SQL Server doesn't automatically enclose date in quotes ' ' . Just like you put in the string to the nchar type, it becomes 'abcd' in the execution. But for the date, it doesn't. Date value goes straight to execute without quotes enclosing.